# [android]how do use a vertical stepper github-code posted by 'ernestoyaquello'

Tags: java, android, github, stepper

i'm interested in android app developing.
I want a make calculating month wage about some job.

so i've watched adaptable source in github. url: https://github.com/ernestoyaquello/VerticalStepperForm
I first moved the usage posted by this developer to my gradle, xml and java. 
But it is because of my lack of basics, I do not know what to do if red letters appear and Where should I include the java code. 
Of course I'm doing a 'build clear' to get rid of the red letters, 
but I'm wondering if I need to create and set all the javafiles as the sample from github I want to use.

also I'm also studying 'android lessons in udacity', and I'd be grateful if you have any other suggestions to improve my coding knowledge and skills.

Comment: It sounds like the 'red letters' are your IDE complaining that it doesn't understand what you're coding. Once you've checked with obvious issues like typos etc, try making sure that you've imported the right references (ctrl + space is often the shortcut. Check your IDE manual)
If that's not it, try posting the code you've written and specifying what is in red so we can see what might be broken